# Jobs: CV completion check reported wrong things missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I just set up my CV and I got the "your matches are on hold" message below. As you can see, it's telling me I need to enter my work experience. Thing is, I'd already entered four jobs AND my college degree. Eventually, I got rid of the message by filling in my personal statement. So, it looks like I was getting the wrong error message.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for pointing this out! Your question brings up some usability concerns that we definitely need to consider for future iterations.

The reason that you saw the "Your matches are on hold" message - even though you've added 4 jobs and a degree - was that Work/Education entries must contain 150+ char. Responsibilities in order to be considered "complete." We recently added a character counter to the Responsibilities field to hint at this requirement, but we're always learning that providing just enough info without being too heavy-handed is an art that we haven't quite mastered :)

As you discovered, you can bypass the Work/Education minimum by adding a 150+ char. Personal Statement instead. Even though we are actively encouraging people to fill out the Work/Education Responsibilities, we will accept a 150+ character Personal Statement - this was a decision made to support past iterations of the CV.

And just for context: based on qualitative feedback from companies, we believe that a "complete" work/education experience entry (including Responsibilities) can provide better information for companies than the Personal Statement. We're hoping (and measuring) that better information for companies will drive better/more responses to you.

Comment: While you're evaluating this requirement from a usability standpoint, I'd like to highlight that the character count UI is highly suggestive of a character _limit_ rather than a _minimum_. For example, one of my experience descriptions reads `56/150 characters` next to the box.

Comment: @BrianD Now that you point this out, I think you're right. I'll bring this up with the team. Maybe a better solution would be to mirror SO's more explicit minimum character prompt, "54 characters to go." It feels a bit wordy, but it _is_ more clear. Thanks for sharing your observation.