# "Your matches are on hold" dialog freezes

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Related: [Jobs: CV completion check reported wrong things missing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316559/jobs-cv-completion-check-reported-wrong-things-missing)

Jobs gives me a dialog to the right that my matches are on hold, because my CV is not complete. Clicking the button will show my education entry (after I deleted my job entry), which has every field filled out. Clicking save will show my personal information box, and the dialog can not be dismissed, or altered, in any way. The page has to be reloaded.

What is even more confusing is that I actually got contacted by a company with an apparently "incomplete" job entry and "incomplete" education entry.

There seem to be several things broken. The "Your matches are on hold" box to the right of the companies page seems to be shown regardless of what is in the CV. The dialog it opens will not save changes, and will then freeze completely causing the user to have to reload the page. The box does not seem to do what it says it does, namely freezing companies not seeing matches with me. What is actually going on here?!

Screenshots:

On the company search page...

[image: "Your matches are on hold"]

...opens...

[image: Wait, everything is filled in?]

...which when you save shows...

[image: Errr... I thought I saved this?]

...which is frozen (none of the buttons works anymore)...

[image: Console]

...which has this shown in the console...

Comment: Happened to me too and it's very annoying.

Comment: Can you give some screenshots?

Comment: Many screenshots were added. Where "many" equals 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your profile was historically more complete and that was why it was included in the index (and why you received queries from employers).

As for the bug itself, I just pushed a fix to prod so you should be able to complete your CV. The root cause was a missing script that was preventing validation errors from being displayed. In this case your work experience is missing tags.

Comment: I guess I have to ask myself what tags I should add to a non-programming job. Or if I should showcase myself as someone that has never worked a day in his life...

Comment: Yeah, that's a tough one. Everybody has to start *somewhere* and you have enough open source on there *and* you've made it clear that you're a student. Honestly, I'm not sure that I'd bother with the non-programming experience. Your call!